DockPanel ind ListItem doesn't stretch
I have a ListView, and I want ListItems with an Image Left, than a text and a second text on the rightside. I have tried different think with Grid and DockPanel, but e.g. the DockPanel doesn't fill the whole width.
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Topliste gesamt" FontSize="16" Margin="10"/>
                    <Grid Background="White" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#25202D" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/HHLogoBack.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TopOverall}" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Beige" LastChildFill="True">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Avatar}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerObj.Name}" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Points}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

Any hints, where I am wrong?

Set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on the ListView. Besides that, consider using the simpler base class ListBox. You only use ListView when you actually set its View property.


Set HorizontalContentAlignment (change style for ListBoxItem)
Set HorizontalAlignment to the last TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"

XAML:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TopOverall}" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Beige" LastChildFill="True">
                <Image Source="{Binding Avatar}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerObj.Name}" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Points}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>

Output:

Hope it helps.
